# Using JSON data in Jquery to populate text boxes

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, cakephp, cakephp-1.2

Ok, so I am using a combination of cakephp 1.2, jquery, and ajax with JSON.  Here is what I'm doing:

When a person inputs an employee id, I get the result of that employee id, if there is one, and I send it back as a `$javascript->object(empInfo)`.  This works fine.  I am returning the information to the function, but I can't seem to process it.  Everything I have read says to use it as `$.each(empInfo, function()`. Here is my code:

COMMON.JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#emp_num').blur(function() {
        if($(this).val().length != 0) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                datatype: "json",
                url: '/ir_employees/getdetails/empId:' + $(this).val(),
                success: function(empInfo) {
                    populateEmployeeInformation(empInfo);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

function populateEmployeeInformation(empInfo) {
    $.each(empInfo, function() {
        console.log(this);
    });
}
```

EMPLOYEES_CONTROLLER.PHP

```
function getdetails() {
    $empId = $this->passedArgs['empId'];
    $this->layout = 'ajax';
    $this->set('empInfo', $this->IrEmployee->find('all', 
                        array('conditions' =>
                                array('IrEmployee.employee_number' => $empId))));

}
```

GETDETAILS.CTP

```
<?php
    if((isset($empInfo))){
        echo $javascript->object($empInfo);
    }

?>
```

When I log it, I get the following (screenshot):

[image: JSON Screen Capture]

How can I use the following information properly (this is the "response" from Firebug):

```
[{"IrEmployee":{"id":"1","employee_number":"xxxxx","last_name":"Doe","first_name":"John","gender":"M","date_hired":"2013-04-09","date_of_birth":"1950-01-01","plant_id":"0"}}]
```

Comment: why shouting capitals everywhere? "EMPLOYEES_CONTROLLER.PHP" thats awefully wrong as filename...

Comment: I'm using all caps as a definition of what I am using.  It's not the actual file name.  file name is employees_controller.php.  I wanted it to stand out.  Thanks for your concern.

Comment: well, don't! it only distracts from the issues at hand.

Comment: Was it answered without someone pitching a fit?  Yes it was.  This is how I notate my stuff on here.  Don't like it, don't look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response is being returned as a string (console.log shows you're looping through each character of the string), and is not being parsed as JSON.

I think this is because you have `datatype` instead of `dataType` (note the uppercase T) in the jQuery AJAX options.  If you fix this, jQuery should automatically parse the JSON for you.

Alternatively, you could pass the string into [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) (if it exists, if not you should [polyfill](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js))

Comment: Stupid Typos...  changing it to `dataType` instead of `datatype` gives me the result I am looking for.  Thank you very much.  Will accept as answer when I can.